# Candy chat installation failed

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe, candy

I have installed open fire server and `http://domain.com/http-bind` is also fine.
And strophe is also working fine.Tried to setup using this setup guide: 
[Candy Setup Guide][1].

I am stucked in Connecting .

`Candy Installation Guide`[1]: http://candy-chat.github.io/candy/#setup "Candy Setup Guide"

```
  Strophe is connecting.
  SENT: <body rid='797907051' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'       to='example.com' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8'  ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>

SENT: <body rid='797907051' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='example.com' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
SENT: <body rid='797907051' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='example.com' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
SENT: <body rid='797907051' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='example.com' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
Strophe is disconnecting.
```

Above is the display output of strophe, I have changed my domian to `example.com`

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   Candy.init('http://example.com/http-bind/', {
   core: {
   debug: true,
   autojoin: ['example@conference.example.com', 'hrirks@conference.example.com']
   },
   view: { resources: 'res/' }
   });

   Candy.Core.connect();
});
```

I copied index.html to candy root directory.
I got following message in firebug console,Response

```
  <html>
  <head><title>Openfire HTTP Binding Service</title></head>
  <body><font face="Arial, Helvetica"><b>Openfire <a href="http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html">HTTP Binding</a> Service</b></font></body>
  </html>
 And got this in POST
  <body rid='3334381189' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='example.com' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
```

Comment: Please share your connection code

Answer (score 0):

You need to call Candy.Core.attach or Candy.Core.connect after init AND include the parameters.

```
Candy.Core.connect(jidOrHost, password, nick);
```

Comment: oops i forget to paste in my question, i called Candy.Core.connect after init

Comment: Are you using connect or attach? Are you sure the credentials are valid? What's the first response? Can you connect to the jabber server using another client such as pidgin?

Comment: ya i can connect using pidgim , and i connected using strophejs example too

Comment: You are not connecting to the jabber server. Are you using connect or attach? Also, add "debug:true" to the core: {} and check the console and report back.

Comment: You're missing something. It's probably failing due to the script error you're getting. You need to step into the debugger and find out what's missing. In order to figure this out, please update your original question with your code that contains your init, the attach or connect and the onconnect callback. Without seeing it, we're just guessing. Also, are you using the latest versions of Candy and Strophe?

Comment: i got following response : <html>
  <head><title>Openfire HTTP Binding Service</title></head>
  <body><font face="Arial, Helvetica"><b>Openfire <a href="http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html">HTTP Binding</a> Service</b></font></body>
</html>

Comment: yes , i am using latest version of CAndy and strophe ,ok i will update the question

Comment: i got the following error: ReferenceError: admin is not defined
Candy.Core.connect(admin , password , hrirks);

Comment: Did you define admin in your script? If it's a user, it should be the full jid. (var admin='user@jabberservername.com')

Comment: Looks like the Openfire server is not configured correctly or you have the wrong path maybe.

Comment: thank you , you are atleast trying to help me :) , but i could not figure out what's the problem

Comment: Can you connect to the rooms you have listed in pidgin? Try only auto connecting to one. If that doesn't work, set autojoin: [] and see what that does

Answer (score 0):

please check if u r missing the exact port , for my case it is domain_name:5280/bosh

Answer (score 0):

There's [a plugin for Openfire](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugin-archive.jsp?plugin=candy) that supplies an integrated version of Candy. There's nothing that you need to configure for that to work, after you installed the plugin.

Side note: Candy has gone unmaintained for a long while. As a result, various important issues are not addressed. You're probably better of using Converse (which similar to the 'candy' plugin, can be added to Openfire by using the '[inVerse' plugin for Openfire](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugin-archive.jsp?plugin=inverse))